# Change CSS color with Javascript on click (addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, css

Okay so I have this div, I want it to turn red when I click on it. Initially it should display as black. If you take and test this code you'll see that it turns red as soon as you load the page.

If I take out the parameter on the click1 function it works fine ish...
It still won't be black initially,  but it will at least change to red when you click on it.

I have a parameter on click1 for the effort of saving on lines of code in the future.
Because ultimately this code is meant to handle multiple squares.
I want to be able to change the color of the squares with JavaScript. I need it to be able to differentiate between each square.  So that it only changes the color of the square that you clicked.
I'd prefer not to make a new function for every square.
That’s why I have it set up the way I do.

All the HTML, CSS and Javascript is right here together.
(Thanks in advance everybody. Its not fun being stuck and frustrated with code. I don't know what i would do without this community. I only wish i could contribute as much as i end up utilizing.)

```html
<body>
  <div class="border">
    <div id="box1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; backgroundColor: #000000;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var colorcheck = "#cccccc";

    function click1(blockid) {
      document.getElementById("box" + blockid).style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
      colorcheck = document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor;
      console.log(colorcheck);
      console.log("box" + blockid);
    };

    document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1(1));
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: it should be `document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1);`. `click(1)` will call the function

Comment: @HAL9000 Check my answer and tell if that suits you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments in `addEventListener`, you have to modified your code like below.

```
 document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", function(){click1(1);}, false);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8j80f8g7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should give the **function reference** and not execute the function there:

```
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1);
//-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Do not "call" the function there.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```js
$('#box1').click(function(){
    $('.border #box1').css('background-color', 'red').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="border">
        <div id="box1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; backgroundColor: #000000;">
        </div>
```

Comment: `with Javascript on click (addEventListener)`

Comment: I am not sure if you understand the question. Again, your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: i thought it is more helpful and easy.. thanks @PraveenKumar to vote me down :)

Comment: There's no jQuery attached to this question. What if this person is using it inside some TamperMonkey script or something?

Comment: @DaanHeskes What about a place where you cannot use jQuery?

Comment: The question was very specific: **Javascript on click (addEventListener)**. I don't understand where you guys come from!

Comment: I removed the downvote. Sorry if I am wrong! Wow! Hail StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add click event in HTML

```
<div onclick="click1()" id="box1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; backgroundColor: #000000;">
```

and remove `document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1(1));`

Comment: Question is clear: **with Javascript on click (addEventListener)**

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned there is an issue in your second `addEventListener` parameter.

You may look at this example:

```js
var colorcheck = "#cccccc";

function click1() {
  document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
  colorcheck = document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor;
  console.log(colorcheck);
  console.log(this.id);
};

document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1);
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div id="box1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #000000;"></div>
</div>
```

PS: look at the style attribute of box1. It's `background-color` not `backgroundColor`. The second one is only for JavaScript.

Comment: I believe `document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor` can be directly used as `this.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, of course you are right but as this is just an example I thought is't a bit easier to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented, `document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1(1))` was issue. Also instead of passing numbers `click1(1)`, you can use `this`.

You can try something like this:

#### Code

```js
var colorcheck = "#cccccc";

function click1(blockid) {
  var self = this;
  self.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
  colorcheck = self.style.backgroundColor;
  console.log(colorcheck);
  console.log("box" + blockid);
};


function registerEvents(){
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  for(var i = 0; i<box.length; i++){
    box[i].addEventListener("click", click1);
  }
}

registerEvents();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="border">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put onclick on the div

```
<div id="box1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; backgroundColor: #000000;"  onclick="click1(1)">
```

And remove the autobinder from script:

```
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", click1(1));
```

Or you can use jQuery, whitch is more elegant to use:

[**Here is an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/microThread/7jtLk47t/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.box', function() {
        var caller = $(this);

  if(caller.hasClass('select-box') == true) {

    caller.removeClass('select-box');

  } else {

    caller.addClass('select-box');

  }
```

});